# sort an array in specific order using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$user=array(
        "20163_100011100001_Guarantor_address_Proof.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Guarantor_Identity_Proof.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Guarantor_Photo.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Member_Address_proof.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Member_Identity_proof.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Member_Photo.jpg"
     );
```

And I want to sort `$user` array in given order

```
$order=array(
        "20163_100011100001_Member_Photo.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Member_Address_proof.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Member_Identity_proof.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Guarantor_Photo.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Guarantor_address_Proof.jpg",
        "20163_100011100001_Guarantor_Identity_Proof.jpg"
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to have `$user` be filled in the right order from the start? Anyhow you could try this

`$order=array(user(6), user(4), user(5), user(3), user(1), user(2))`

Comment: $user array is taken in randomly.

Comment: As DarkBee suggested, you could use `sort` to sort `$user` alphabetically and change the code handling whatever you want with this array to accept `$user` alphabetically.